# Merge polygons that overlap into a multipart polygon while maintaining the original geometries/look

Tags: union, chart, index

Overall, I want to display an index map that shows nautical charts and their corresponding inset charts. The majority of the time these insets lay directly on top of the "parent" chart in a given location. I want to be able to illustrate to clients that within this parent chart, they will also receive the inset chart. In our systems current status, I need to make this work with a multipart polygon. Is there a union or similar tool that allows something like this? In the picture, red outline = inset chart and purple = parent chart. [image: Chart display issues]

Comment: If you don't mind the slight change in area and the presence of a gap (visible only when zoomed in and even then visually filled by outer line thickess) you could create a very small buffer of your inset polys and then erase a bit of the larger polygon around them with it to create a gap.  Or apply a small negative buffer and erase a bit of the inset polys.